# Facebook login redirection issue - using oauth 2.0 sdk with oauth 1.0

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I know this question is being asked many times :)

Im stuck with using oauth 1.0 with facebook as I am doing certain things with the tab. The php-sdk that I am using supports oauth 2.0. I have set not to use oauth 2.0 in app's "advance settings", so my tab works good with oauth 1.0, but the canvas keeps redirecting as its not able to authenticate the user due to the sdk supporting 2.0.

What can I do to make it compatible and working?

Thanks in advance.